# display two images in theme header.php file

Tags: custom-post-types, themes

I would like to display two images in my header.

functions.php:

```
define('BP_DTHEME_DISABLE_CUSTOM_HEADER', true);

//add support for featured images with post type of header image
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array('header_image') ); 

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'header_image',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Header Image' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Header Image' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('thumbnail') //(featured image, current theme must also support post-thumbnails)
        )
    );
}
```

header.php:

```
        <?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'header_image');
            $header_images = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php   foreach($image as $header_images){ ?>
                <div class="header-image">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($image, 'thumbnail'); ?>
                </div>
        <?php       
            }               
        ?>
```

Now I have two problems:

1) I am getting a php error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in header.php

2) Where do I append two image paths to the header_image post type array so that i can reference the two images in header.php?

thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using the WordPress `loop` instead of a foreach, since you're using WP_Query.

```
 <?php if( $header_images->have_posts() ) { while( $header_images->have_posts() ) { $header_images->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="header-image">
           <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
      </div>
 <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: This is giving me a parse error on the first line of your code

Comment: Sorry I was missing a closing paranthesis. Fixed.

Comment: Im still a little confused. How is someone supposed to add the thumbnail? Or should this be asked in another question?

Comment: @JohnMerlino Well in your code above, you added thumbnail support for your custom post type. So, to add a thumbnail, you should add / edit a post in your custom post type admin section, and add a featured image there.

Comment: Im still having problems with uploading. I get this error: Unable to create directory /Users/johnmerlino/Documents/github/cms/wp-content/uploads/2012/06. Is its parent directory writable by the server?  It doesn't seem to be uploading to right place.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your order wrong on your `foreach`.

`<?php   foreach($image as $header_images){ ?>`

Should be

`<?php   foreach($header_images as $image ){ ?>`

Since you're using a `WP_Query`, be sure to use `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after the closing bracket of your `foreach`.

Comment: True that the order in his `foreach` is wrong, but `$header_images` is a `WP_Query` object. I don't see how his code would work even with the proper `foreach` order, unless he did a `foreach( $header_images->posts as $image )`. No?

Comment: `foreach` works for arrays and objects - I was simply fixing the parse error.  Since `foreach` will work, the OP will need to check out exactly what's being returned as $image inside the foreach and code accordingly.  There's usually multiple ways of getting info from a WP_Query object, and your way above is just as good (although it does need an `endwhile` and a `wp_reset_query()` after).